# jquery update <input name = [i]> if DOM is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Im new to jQuery and i have a problem that i would appreciate if you could help me with.

I have a form/list of elements (from db) generated when a user click a link.
Each element has a remove button generated with jQuery. The button removes it self and the input textbox if clicked.
I also have a add new texbox button. This button creates a new textbox and the remove button.

All my textboxes has a name[i] -value;

```
name[1]  
name[2] 
name[3]
... 
...
```

The thing is when i remove a textbox the value is just removed *(like i--)*. Old values are not updated.
On my post back i only get values from textboxes that are "in order" i.e if a texbox value is skipped like

> ```
> name[1]  
> name[2]  
> name[4] 
> name[5]
> ...
> ```

it will not be returned. (In this case, i will only get value name[1](http://jsfiddle.net/6vmMy/1/) and [2] back).

I need help how i can build a array and store all my values to the array. Then update all my values from the array.

**This i my javascript code:**

> $(function () {
>       var scntDiv = $('#TextBoxesGroup');
>
> ```
> var i = $('#TextBoxesGroup p').size();
>
> $('#addButton').live('click', function () {
> ```

- //line brakes to make it more readable

> ```
>  $('<p>
>         <label for="Students_' + i + '__Name">Name: </label>
>         <input type="text" class="text-box single-line" id="Students_' + i + '__Name" size="20" name="Students[' + i + '].Name" placeholder="Student name..." /> 
>         <button id="remove">Remove</button>
>     </p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
>     i++;
>     return false;
> });
>
> $('#remove').live('click', function () {
>     if (i >= 0) {
>         $(this).parents('p').remove();
>         i--;
>         var array = $('#TextBoxesGroup p')
>         alert(array.length);
>     }
>     return false;
> }); });
> ```

Here is fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/6vmMy/1/

Comment: A fiddle of your work and problem will be better for us to help SIR! Create one here : http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Assuming all your inputs are in the correct order including the related corresponding ones, you can omit the indexes and simply use `name[]` for all of them. All back-ends languages that I'm aware of support that syntax.

Comment: FYI, the `.live()` has been removed from jQuery 1.9+, please use `.on()` instead

Comment: @AspiringAqib http://jsfiddle.net/6vmMy/

Comment: I want to see your rendered markup HTML as this seems odd to me.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss ok. Is till use 1.8. But thanks!

Comment: Your fiddle performs an invalid action adding a duplicate ID to the DOM for the remove button.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss thats not the problem. I can change that to class    http://jsfiddle.net/6vmMy/2/

Comment: Yes, but you see the crux of your issue is that you are using the index as an ID and name in your inputs also, and thus changing those once added to the DOM will be problematic, especially for the id's that will be a challenge to update in the rendered DOM.  It might be time to rethink your methodology regarding an array of elements.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss ok. Suggestions? :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you taking a look at the [`following article`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) which illustrates a much better alternative of achieving your goal by using non-sequential indexes which are supported by the default model binder. This way you will not be leaving *holes* in your indexes when removing elements and it will make your code much easier. Also the author of the article provided a nice custom HTML helper called `Html.BeginCollectionItem` which allows you to hide away all the plumbing that is necessary to generate the proper markup.

Remark: `.live()` has been removed in jQuery 1.9. You should use the `.on()` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

I sense you would like to have at least one student, so I would put one in the markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="TextBoxesGroup"> <span>
        Press to add textbox and remove button    
         </span>
    </div>
    <p class="students">
        <label>Name:
            <input type="text" class="text-box single-line" size="20" placeholder="Student name..."
            />
        </label>
        <button class="removeStudent">Remove</button>
    </p>
    <input type='button' value="Add more Students" id="addButton"  />
</div>
```

Then, I would simply manipulate that one to add more: (verbose to show steps etc, could consolidate a bit)

```
$(function () {
    var scntDiv = $('#TextBoxesGroup');
    $('#addButton').click(function () {
        var lastStudent= $(".students").last();
        var newName =  lastStudent.clone();
        newName.find('.single-line.text-box').val("new student");
        lastStudent.after(newName);
    });
    $('#container').on('click', '.removeStudent', function () {
        if ($('.students').length > 1) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

This clones the last one, inserting it after the last one, and always keeps at least one student, and allows removal of any one of those.  Otherwise, I would look into the answer provided by Darin.